# Google App Invites Email Not Sent After Play Services Update to 8.3, SMS OK

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I upgraded play services to 8.3.0 and android studio preview 2 and since then my app invites won't deliver to email address. Sms works fine. It accepts my requests but nothing happens.

I tried out the sample app and that seems fine but with my app it doesn't work.

I'm testing on a debug key and I deleted and recreated everything got a brand new google-services.json file, nothing works.

I'm suspecting the package name might have some sort of a block from Google side? Can you guys please take a look?

Package name: com.fitzo.android

Answer (score 0):

I'll need some clarification. You say sms works fine, but nothing happens, so what indicates that sms is fine? If you send an email invite, after send do you get a failed notification, or success? Is it just that the email is not received? More details would really help me. Thx.

The app packagename and key need to be entered in the developer console to generate a Client ID. You mentioned using a debug key. Is this the same key that worked earlier? If not, you need to create a second set of credentials in the developer console (you can have more than one).

The changes you made(upgrading to 8.3.0 and android studio), should not effect your results. However we can explore that avenue if nothing else seems to work.

Generally if you can connect to the servers for any server call, then your configuration is correct. In the invite activity, do you get "Suggestions from Google", or just the "Everyone" list? If you don't get Suggestions, then you likely are not connecting to the server, and nothing will work including creating invitations using either email or sms. Make sure the sender account has some account activity, such as sending emails.